# SVG lines not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to draw a rectangle as four lines. The problem is that the top and left lines appear to be thinner and there is a missing pixel at the right bottom corner (See Screenshot).

HTML svg element :

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" width="500" height="500" style="
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="20" y2="0" class="line"></line>
    <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="20" y2="20" class="line"></line>
    <line x1="20" y1="20" x2="0" y2="20" class="line"></line>
    <line x1="0" y1="20" x2="0" y2="0" class="line"></line></svg>
</svg>
```

rendered result in the browser :
[[image: rectangle with some thinner lines]

Comment: What does your `css` define for `class="line"`? Try adding `stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;` to the class definition.

Comment: @daShier .line defines just the stroke color to be black. Adding  stroke-linecap:square; solved the missing pixel. But the right and bottom lines are still  thicker.

Comment: On an SVG markup note, you seem to be missing the `<svg viewBox="...">` attribute, which determines how the on-page dimensions (the width and height, which are only for "the thing showing the SVG file") map to the in-image coordinates (which are inherently unit-less, and only have meaning inside the SVG document). The viewBox gives the "cropping" rectangle and says what part of the SVG document should get drawn, and width/height then tell the owner what phyislcal size to draw that at. Eg `width="10px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 1 2"` is 10x20 on page, showing everything between (0,0) and (1,2)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans you can omit the viewBox if you don't want the drawing to scale its container scales. Sometimes that's what you want.

Comment: Sometimes, but that's _very_ rare in an standard HTML context, where the main reason you're using SVG is exactly because it's scalable vector graphics.

Answer (score 3):

Only the stroke of a line is visible and it extends equally each side of it. So if you draw a single line from 0, 0 to 100, 0 and the line has width 2 then that line will actually occupy a rectangle with corners (-1, -1), (101, -1), (101, 1), (-1, 1).

So your rectangle's lines are partially outside the drawing canvas and those parts that are outside are not visible.

Also if you want to draw a square you'll need to draw some of the lines longer so that you get a square effect at the corners. Alternatively use a `<path>` and it will handle the corners without you having to worry about it.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 40 40" style="
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
">
    <path d="M0,0 20,0 20,20 0,20Z" fill="none" stroke="black" transform="translate(1,1)" />
</svg>
```

or you could just move the canvas e.g.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" width="500" height="500" viewBox="-2 -2 40 40" style="
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
">
    <path d="M0,0 20,0 20,20 0,20Z" fill="none" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```

Comment: So offsetting the `x coordinates by 2 would fix it for the OP, or can the canvas origin be set to -2,-2?

Comment: You can do either. I've updated my answer to show both.

Comment: also note that SVG has the `strokeWidth` attribute available on all shape elements. Not strictly at play here, but better than CSS if you do need to control the thickness of an SVG shape's outline.

Comment: strokeWidth is a CSS property that also happens to be available as a mapped attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Or, in the shortest possible form:

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="-1 -1 22 22">
  <path d="M0,0H20V20H0z" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've re-written your SVG with a few small changes and it seems to be working fine.

There are **four** main changes:

1. `<line />` is a self-closing element.
2. I have explicitly given each `line` a `stroke-width` of `1`
3. Wherever you have used a co-ordinate of `0`, I have used `1`
4. I have given each `line` a `stroke-linecap` of `square`

I have also reduced the `viewBox` to `100 x 100` so you can see the square much larger.

**Working Example:**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100">

<defs>
<style type="text/css"><![CDATA[

svg {
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
padding: 20px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.line {
stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255);
stroke-width: 1;
stroke-linecap: square;
}

]]></style>
</defs>

<line x1="1" y1="1" x2="21" y2="1" class="line" />
<line x1="21" y1="1" x2="21" y2="21" class="line" />
<line x1="21" y1="21" x2="1" y2="21" class="line" />
<line x1="1" y1="21" x2="1" y2="1" class="line" />

</svg>
```